# webpage body background with multiple images

Tags: css, image, background

I am trying to create a webpage background with multiple images

i.e

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body
top image(no reapeat)
middle image(repeat y) 
bottom image(no repeat)>
</body>
</html>
```

I have cut 1 image into 3 parts so that the middle image can grow according to the size of the body text

please advise how I can do this

Answer (score 1):

Multiple background can be achieve using many ways, but CSS3 allow to use multiple background image,

```
$body {
background-image: url(bg1.png) url(bg2.png) url(bg2.png);
background-repeat: 5% 90% 5%;
```

}

But most of the old browser did not support css3, there is another way using sprites like yahoo main page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple divs and each one has a background

```
<div style="background: url('image1.jpg');">
    <div style="background: url('image2.jpg');">
        <div style="background: url('image3.jpg');">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `div` in head, body, footer section of page and set these images in these divs accordingly.